# Wicket: error while processing form; how to skip to onError()?

Tags: java, forms, wicket, form-processing

I have an `AjaxFallbackButton` on my page with its `onSubmit` and `onError` methods overridden. What is the best practice for dealing with exceptions/errors in the `onSubmit` method? Should I just stop processing it, register the error and call `onError` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
   ... // error 
      form.error("An exception was thrown")
      onError();
      return;
}
```

or is there a better way?

Comment: You don 't need to call onError(). Just add an error to the form /formelement and be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have specific logic in `onError` (like setting a response page, rolling back a transaction, etc), Wicket doesn't demand you calling it.

In any case, there is no alternative, other than ensuring you check everything in validators attached to your form components and form, thus preventing the exception from ever happening in the first place.